# retrieve data from Wikipedia and show it using angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to get data from wikipedia and show it in the front end.
I retrived the data from wiki using the following php code

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&titles=Sachin_Tendulkar&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
echo json_encode($json);
```

following is my **controller**

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);
demoApp.controller('SimpleController',function ($scope,$http){
    $http.post('server/view1.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.info = data;
    });
});
```

my **html** is as follows

```
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title> AngularJS Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
        {{info.query}} // I dont know if this is right
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display all the content that is retrieved in the front end but it is not showing up. I dont know what I have done wrong. I am a newbie to angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my answer.

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <title> AngularJS Sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
            <div ng-bind-html='info'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngSanitize']);
demoApp.controller('SimpleController',function ($scope,$http){
    $http.post('server/view1.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.info = data;
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Sachin_Tendulkar&format=json&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids';
$jsonString = json_decode(file_get_contents( $url ),true);
$pageData = $jsonString['query']['pages'][57570]['extract'];
echo $pageData;
```

Comment: That does indeed work as a solution. However, it seems as though there should be a way to do this without creating the php script.

Answer (score 5):

Skip the PHP Part and use Angular JSONP with the following parameter:

```
format=json
callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

So Angular can understand and parse the Wiki Answer:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnlimit=1&rawcontinue&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
    method: 'jsonp'
}).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.response = response;
});
```

This works also with [action=parse](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) to get an article.

If you want to display the raw json response on the page, use the json filter:

```
<pre>{{ response | json }}</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the given URL, you get a JSON-formatted response. Why do you encoding a JSON respons to JSON? That's not needed, so skip that part.

```
<?php
$url ='http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&titles=Sachin_Tendulkar&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
echo json;
?>
```

Just open [the url](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&titles=Sachin_Tendulkar&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids), you can see the reponse.

In your example, your php code is pretty useless. Maybe you can use the API directly in your controller:

```
$http.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?[....]').success(function(data){
    $scope.info = data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But still the data is not showing up in front end. I think I am doing something wrong in the html code. but dont know what.

Comment: Take a look at your console in your browser (F12 in Chrome). It will give you usefull information about post/get requests and client side (js) errors.

Comment: it displays `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error on console when I tried the API directly in my controller